# Reuse PDO query outside of loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I have a loop which queries a mysql db using pdo, I want to be able to use the returned results elsewhere outside of the loop using echo. Is this possible, tried just echoing outside of the loop it didnt work for obvious reasons.

```
$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM x WHERE id = '.$id);
foreach($data as $row) 
{
print $row['z'];
}
```

How can I reuse `$row['z']` outside of the loop, is it possible?

Comment: So, you just want to keep the last results rows `z` then?

Comment: @mario not sure what you mean.

Comment: Yes it's possible, you can use `$var=$row['z'];` then `echo $var;`

Comment: create something like $array[] = $row['z']; then you can use it everywhere. also dont use print if it is not needed and escape $id.

Comment: You're welcome. Did you happen to use what I mentioned? @abushahin just curious.

Comment: I had put an answer in originally, but someone thought that it would not work. We can close the question with my answer below if you would like. @abushahin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you can use `$var=$row['z'];` then `echo $var;`

```
$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM x WHERE id = '.$id);
    foreach($data as $row) 
    {
    print $row['z'];
    $var=$row['z'];
    }

echo $var;
```

or:

```
$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM x WHERE id = '.$id);
    foreach($data as $row) 
    {
    print $row['z'];

    }

    $var=$row['z'];
echo $var;
```

Comment: Yeah I had a doubt myself. I had the `$var` outside the loop originally. @WigglerJtag

Comment: Probably. Did you try it? I tried to Google for a 1/2 hour last night, but couldn't find anything better. @abushahin

Comment: No I didn't but will eventually want to concatenate all the values from that same row (int). I'll let you know once I try it. I couldn't find anything on Google too hence the question here. Thought the downvotes on the question were because of duplicate question?  Even though I couldn't find anything here either.

Comment: I will also see what else I can come up with, and let you know if I do find something that will work better. @abushahin